# puppeteer doesnt work in nohup mode but works normaly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

Ive made a node js web scraper with puppeteer.
I want it to run 24/7 so I tried running it on a aws ec2 virtual machine.
if I run the program normally "npm start" it works perfectly, but beacause I want to close the ssh connection and go about my day, Ive tried running "nohup npm start &" but when I run it like that I either get an error in 'nohup.out':

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
```

or just the code stops running and nothing happens

Comment: I would consider running it in screen or tmux so you can reconnect later

Answer (score 0):

ended up just using

```
ctrl + z
bg
disown -a
```

instead